# Who proved the upper bound for the autocorrelation of higher order divisor functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Who first published a proof that

$$\sum_{n\leq x}d_{k}(n)d_k(n+h)=O(x(\log x)^{2k-2})$$

for fixed $k$ and $h$ please? I am struggling to find a reference. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked either Handbook of Number Theory or Handbook of Number Theory II?  You should be able to find a reference there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if it was the first, but the bounds would follow from the main theorem in

*Nair, Mohan; Tenenbaum, G\'erald*, [**Short sums of certain arithmetic functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392880), Acta Math. 180, No.1, 119-144 (1998). [ZBL0917.11048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0917.11048).

See also the more uniform bounds (in your case, this would give uniformity in $h$, after taking the singular series into account) obtained in

*Henriot, Kevin*, [**Nair-Tenenbaum bounds uniform with respect to the discriminant**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004111000752), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 152, No. 3, 405-424 (2012); erratum ibid. 157, No. 2, 375-377 (2014). [ZBL1255.11048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1255.11048).

The result also follows from the properties of the pseudorandom majorants for multiplicative functions such as $d_k$ that were constructed by Matthiesen, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04482

Comment: Great. Thank you. In [Bounds and Conjectures for additive divisor sums](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01411), Nathan Ng and Mark Thom also cite: A. Ivic, The general additive divisor problem and moments of the zeta-function, New trends in proba- bility and statistics, Vol. 4 (Palanga, 1996), 69-89, VSP, Utrecht, 1997.